# Populate one selection list according to the value selected in another selection list

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm making an interface using jsp. and I've two selection lists. I've to populate the second selection list based on the value in the 1st selction list.

Exmaple:

Selection list one has: GSM, CDMA

then,

if user selects GSM, he should see CRICKET, COMBO OFFER, ASTRO in selection list 2. Or if user selects CDMA, he should see COMBO OFFER CDMA, VOICE CHAT, WIN THE DREAM in selection list 2

can anybody please help me out?

THIS IS THE CODE

```
<tr>
<td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICE:</b></font> </td>
<td><select name="service" >
<option value="GSM">GSM</option>
<option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
</select>
</td>


<td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VAS :</b></font> </td>
<td><select name="service" >
<option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>
<option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
<option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
<option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>
<option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
<option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Depends of if you can pick a value in the second select only using javascript or if you need to go via server

Comment: What is the input for the first select and second select . Are you passing the list from server side ?

Comment: it's hardcoded as in this example.

Comment: input for the 1st and second select ? i didn't get you.

Comment: let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function optionsChange(){   
        var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
        if(service == 'GSM'){   
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'block';
        }else if(service == 'CDMA'){
            document.getElementById("gsmService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICE:</b></font> </td>
        <td><select id="service" name="service" onChange="javascript:optionsChange();">
                <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
                <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VAS :</b></font> </td></tr>
    <tr id="gsmService">
        <td><select name="gsmService" > 
                <option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>
                <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
                <option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
            </select>   
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="cdmaService">
        <td><select name="cdmaService" >
            <option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
            <option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
            <option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```